# timer countdown in reactjs doesn't works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, countdown

> I'm building a web application that counts clicks in one second, but
> the countdown (from 5 to 0) doesn't work. the countdown should go down every second(1000ms). i've tried with setInterval() but it doesn't work and now i don't know what i have to do

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.scss';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    cps: 0,
    seconds: 5,
    target: '',
  }

  five = 5000;

  fiveSeconds = () => {
    this.increment = () => {
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1,
      })
    }
    this.countdown = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ seconds: this.state.seconds - 1})
      
      if (this.state.seconds <= 0){
        this.setState({ seconds: 0 });
      }
    }, 1000)

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ target: 'true', cps: this.state.count/this.five*1000 });

      if(this.state.count == 59){
        this.setState({ cps: 11.8 })
      }
    }, this.five)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 id="counter-title">COUNTER: <a href="/" id="counter">{this.state.count}</a></h3>
        <h3 id="counter-title">CPS: {this.state.cps}</h3>
        <h3>TIMER: {this.state.seconds}</h3>
        <br/>
        <button disabled={this.state.target} id="btn" onClick={this.fiveSeconds}>CLICK HERE TO START</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61791234/how-to-display-countdown-timer-in-react

Answer (score 0):

I dropped your code into a react playground and it seems to count down from 5 correctly. The real issue is that you can click the button multiple times which will trigger the fiveSeconds function for each click, this will make the countdown go significantly faster.

The button should either be disabled after the first click by setting your 'target' state variable to true first thing in the fiveSeconds function, or the function fiveSeconds should only be run once. One way to do that is to add a new state variable called ex. startFlag initialized as false and have fiveSeconds set it to true as soon as it is clicked. Then put a ternary on the button, ex. onClick={this.setFlag === false ? this.fiveSeconds : null}.